# Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance, linq

Suppose I had a string:

```
string str = "1111222233334444";
```

How can I break this string into chunks of some size?

E.g., breaking this into sizes of 4 would return strings:

```
"1111"
"2222"
"3333"
"4444"
```

Comment: Why use LINQ or regexes when C#'s standard string manipulation functions can do this with less effort and more speed? Also, what happens if the string is an odd number of characters in length?

Comment: I'd like to avoid loops etc. I think it can be done in one line using LINQ/regex.

Comment: "I'd like to avoid loops" - why?

Comment: This scenario is part of much bigger problem (the string is also much bigger) and IMO using loops, chopping strings etc. is not very elegant. StringLength % 4 will always be 0. Do you think using loops is the only solution? I do not want to compromise on performance.So what is the best solution? TIA.

Comment: Using a simple loop is definitely what gives the best performance.

Comment: you sure that Linq would be more performant than a for loop? I wonder what the difference in underlining CLR language would end up being.  If this really is a performance bottleneck, which would seem strange, then you'd want to line up some stress testing so you'll know which is faster for the load you expect.

Comment: http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/blog/200909/linq-vs-loop-performance is a pretty good comparison between linq and actual looping over an array. I doubt you'll ever find linq faster than manually written code because it keeps calling run-time delegates that are hard to optimize away. Linq is more fun though :)

Comment: Whether you're using LINQ or regexes, the loop is still there.

Comment: [As of .Net 6 there's a native Chunk method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459077/861716).

Answer (score 302, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}
```

Please note that additional code might be required to gracefully handle edge cases (`null` or empty input string, `chunkSize == 0`, input string length not divisible by `chunkSize`, etc.). The original question doesn't specify any requirements for these edge cases and in real life the requirements might vary so they are out of scope of this answer.

Comment: @Konstantin much more elegant but will it deal with case of string not being a factor of 4?  e.g. string str = "111122223333444455";

Comment: Will check to see which solution performs best. Konstantin's is easy to follow though IMO.

Comment: @dove: red_Amazon in comments to his question said that str.Length % 4 == 0

Comment: @Konstantin ah, didn't see that comment.  could make my for loop a one-liner.

Comment: @Harry Good catch! This can be remedied with a drop-in ternary expression on the count parameter of substring. Something like: `(i * chunkSize + chunkSize <= str.Length) ? chunkSize : str.Length - i * chunkSize`.

An additional problem is that this function doesn't account for str being null. This can be fixed by wrapping the whole return statement in another ternary expression: `(str != null) ? ... : Enumerable.Empty<String>();`.

Comment: This was close, but unlike the previous 30 upvoters, I had to change the loop count limit of Range from `str.Length / chunkSize` to `double length = str.Length; double size = chunkSize; int count = (int)Math.Ceiling(length/size); return Enumerable.Range(0, count)...`

Comment: I'd like to keep the code short just to illustrate the idea. I'm sure people will be able to add error handling etc. themselves.

Comment: @KonstantinSpirin I agree if the code worked. It only handles the case where a string is a multiple of chunkSize, the rest of the string is lost. Please ammend. Also keep in mind that LINQ and it's magic is not as easy to understand to someone that just wants to look at a solution to this problem. A person must now understand what the Enumerable.Range() and .Select() functions do. I will not argue that you should have an understanding of that to write C#/.NET  code as these functions have been in the BCL for many years now.

Comment: Topic starter said in comments that `StringLength % 4 will always be 0`. If `Linq` is not as easy to understand then there are other answers that use loops and yields. Anyone is free to choose the solution she likes best. You can post your code as an answer and people will happily vote for it.

Comment: @gap, good stuff. Konstantin, why not just modify the answer. I mean, it literally is just to add the call to Math.Ceiling... #gosh.

Comment: I posted an updated version of this method that works if "str.Length % chunkSize" is not zero

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann your solution is completely different from my original intention of writing a simple one-liner. I'd prefer if you posted your proposal as a separate answer.

Comment: I like it - as a coding exercise. For an actual program I'd claim a straightforward for loop is much preferable. Code should be obvious, ideally both in intent and implementation details. This has a reasonable signature and so the intent is reasonably clear, but the implementation is obscure. And slow. And wasteful of memory. A simple for (i=0; i < n; i += chunkSize) loop would be far superior in all aspects except amount of code, but six lines of simple code is still better than one or two WTF lines of code. Still, like I said, I do think it's an elegant solution.

Comment: maybe an extension method for string?

Comment: @ComeIn only if you often have to do this (>10 times in your project?). Otherwise it'll just pollute IntelliSense with not much added value.

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0, (str.Length + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, Math.Min(str.Length - i * chunkSize, chunkSize)))

Comment: worked for me, i have given a if condition like `if (str.Length < chunkSize)
                chunkSize = str.Length;` , otherwise if the chunk size is less than string length the output was null. So total code is `public IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
        {
            if (str.Length < chunkSize)
                chunkSize = str.Length;
            return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
                .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
        }`

Comment: good thought, but I would need it to break on whole words also, not split a word in half.

Comment: `static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (str.Length + chunkSize -1) / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, (i * chunkSize + chunkSize <= str.Length) ? chunkSize : str.Length - i * chunkSize));
}`

Answer (score 180):

In a combination of [dove's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450796#1450796) and [Konstatin's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450797#1450797)...

```
static IEnumerable<string> WholeChunks(string str, int chunkSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkSize)
        yield return str.Substring(i, chunkSize);
}
```

This will work for all strings that can be split into a whole number of chunks, and will throw an exception otherwise.

If you want to support strings of any length you could use the following code:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ChunksUpto(string str, int maxChunkSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += maxChunkSize)
        yield return str.Substring(i, Math.Min(maxChunkSize, str.Length-i));
}
```

However, the the OP explicitly stated he does *not* need this; it's somewhat longer and harder to read, slightly slower.  In the spirit of [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#In_software_development) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), I'd go with the first option: it's probably the most efficient implementation possible, and it's very short, readable, and, importantly, throws an exception for nonconforming input.

Comment: +1 worth a nod. kinda hits nail upon head.  he's looking for succinct sytnax and you're also giving the (probably) better performance.

Comment: And if you make it "static ... Chunk(this string str, int chunkSize) {" you even have one more "new" C#-Feature into it. Then you can write "1111222233334444".Chunk(4).

Comment: @MartinStettner: That's certainly a decent idea if this is a common operation.

Comment: You should only include the latter code. The former requires that you understand and test for the string being a multiple of chunk size prior to using, or understand that it will not return the remainder of the string.

Comment: The OP's question doesn't make it clear whether he needs that functionality.  The first solution is simpler, faster and reliably fails with an exception iff the string cannot be evenly split into the specified chunk size.   I agree that returning "wrong" results would be bad, but that not what it does - it just throws an exception, so I'd be OK with using it if you can live with the limitation.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing: update, the OP explicitly stated he doesn't need non-whole chunks.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne I understand your stating that is more clear, however, its a bug beartrap waiting to be sprung on the unsuspecting. Happy that you've included the other solution :)

Comment: To each his own.  It just depends what you want - the other variant can generate chunks that are smaller than the chunk size - which might cause bugs of its own, especially if you _initially_ always had whole chunk sizes (like the OP).  All else being equal, I like strong post-conditions, so if you have whole chunk sizes, I'd prefer that to be guarranteed and invalid input to be detected rather than potentially buggy output (too short chunks) to be generated (i.e. fail-fast).  Of course, if you expect non-whole size chunks it's a different story.

Comment: I've renamed the methods - would that mitigate the potential confusion?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne The first approach is good as dove way. As Konstantin way left remained characters without exception and Dove way select all items without care about their length your second way throw an exception and i didn't understand meaning of 'If you want to support strings of any length ' because of error thrown. I chose the first way. +1 anyway and appreciate if you describe more about second. I read your comment about prefer exception on buggy(too short chunk) output. I think it is better to write code can hint and get output rather exception .

Comment: @QMaster: It's generally a good idea to [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) in cases like these because this is code that is not immediately user-facing, and therefore unexpected behavior will generally cause hard-to-debug errors down the line.  So it's best to detect and halt on an unsupported edge-case (such as a string that doesn't divide cleanly into chunks) since that way the consumer can quickly and cheaply decide what to do, rather that after a long and expensive debugging session.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne you right in special usage but in public purpose i think the programmer need a function can handle various situation. additionally i had mistake and wrote way one and two contrariwise. The first way get exception and second get chunk in any sizes as you said. I'm sorry and thanks to you'r explanation.

Comment: Need to handle the case where the last chunk size is less than given size, otherwise will throw an error (https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/divide+string+in+chunks+c%23)

Answer (score 64):

Use loops. Here's something that would do it quite well:

```
string str = "111122223333444455";
int chunkSize = 4;
int stringLength = str.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength ; i += chunkSize)
{
    if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength  - i;
    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(i, chunkSize));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't know how you'd deal with case where the string is not factor of 4, but I am not saying you're idea is not possible, just wondering the motivation for it if a simple for loop does it very well.  Obviously the above could be cleaned up and even put in as an extension method.

Or as mentioned in comments, you know it's /4 then

```
str = "1111222233334444";
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(i, chunkSize));
}
```

Comment: You can pull `int chunkSize = 4` outside of the loop. It will only be modified on the final pass.

Comment: +1 for a simple and effective solution - this is how I would have done it, although I would've used `i += chunkSize` instead.

Comment: Probably a minor quibble, but you should probably also pull the `str.Length` out of the loop and into a local variable.  The C# optimizer *may* be able to inline array length, but I think the code as written will do a method call on every loop, which is not efficient, since the size of `str` never changes.

Comment: @Daniel, put your idea in there.  though I'm not sure that this wouldn't be calculated at runtime, but that's another question ;)

Comment: @Daniel coming back to this, pretty sure the that this optimisation would be extracted by the compiler.

Comment: THIS WORKED well @dove

Answer (score 49):

This is based on [dove's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555658/706456), but implemented as an extension method.

Benefits:

- Extension method
- Covers corner cases
- Splits string with any chars: numbers, letters, other symbols

Code

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int chunkLength)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new ArgumentException();
        if (chunkLength < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkLength)
        {
            if (chunkLength + i > str.Length)
                chunkLength = str.Length - i;

            yield return str.Substring(i, chunkLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy(3); // bob, joe, cat
```

Unit tests removed for brevity ([see the previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8944374/5)).

Comment: Interesting solution, but for the sake of avoiding checks beyond null on the input, it seems more logical to allow an empty string to just return a single empty-string part: `if (str.Length == 0) yield return String.Empty; else { for... }`

Comment: I mean, that's how the normal String.Split handles empty strings; it returns one empty-string entry.

Comment: Side note: your usage example is wrong. You can't just cast `IEnumerable` to array, especially not implicitly.

Comment: I personally like to call that method `Chunkify`.. It's not mine, I don't remember where I have seen that name, but it felt very nice to me

Answer (score 46):

Starting with .NET 6, we can also use the [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) method:

```
var result = str
    .Chunk(4)
    .Select(x => new string(x))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 45):

Using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
List<string> groups = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\d{4}")
                       select m.Value).ToList();
```

I find this to be more readable, but it's just a personal opinion. It can also be a one-liner : ).

Comment: Change the pattern to @"\d{1,4}" and it works for any string length. :)

Comment: +1 Though this is slower than the other solutions, it's definitely very readable.  It's not clear to me whether the OP requires digits or arbitrary characters; it'd probably be wise to replace the `\d` character class with a `.` and to specify `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: or just Regex.Matches(s, @"\d{1,4}").Select(m => m.Value).ToList(); I never got the point of this alternative syntax that serves only to obfuscate that we're using extension methods.

Answer (score 26):

Use this for a one-liner:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>(Regex.Split(target, @"(?<=\G.{4})", RegexOptions.Singleline));
```

With this regex it doesn't matter if the last chunk is less than four characters, because it only ever looks at the characters behind it.

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient solution, but I just had to toss it out there.

Comment: in case of `target.Lenght % ChunckSize == 0` that returns a additional empty row e.g `List<string> result = new List<string>(Regex.Split("fooo", @"(?<=\G.{4})", RegexOptions.Singleline));`

Answer (score 9):

It's not pretty and it's not fast, but it works, it's a one-liner and it's LINQy:

```
List<string> a = text.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i }).GroupBy(o => o.Index / 4).Select(g => new String(g.Select(o => o.Char).ToArray())).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that GroupBy preserves order of elements?

Comment: `ToCharArray` is unnecessary since `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had to write something that accomplishes this at work, so I thought I would post my solution to this problem. As an added bonus, the functionality of this solution provides a way to split the string in the opposite direction and it does correctly handle Unicode characters as previously mentioned by Marvin Pinto. So, here it is:

```
using System;
using Extensions;

namespace TestCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string asciiStr = "This is a string.";
            string unicodeStr = "これは文字列です。";

            string[] array1 = asciiStr.Split(4);
            string[] array2 = asciiStr.Split(-4);

            string[] array3 = asciiStr.Split(7);
            string[] array4 = asciiStr.Split(-7);

            string[] array5 = unicodeStr.Split(5);
            string[] array6 = unicodeStr.Split(-5);
        }
    }
}

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string that are seperated a given fixed length.</summary>
        /// <param name="s">This string object.</param>
        /// <param name="length">Size of each substring.
        ///     <para>CASE: length &gt; 0 , RESULT: String is split from left to right.</para>
        ///     <para>CASE: length == 0 , RESULT: String is returned as the only entry in the array.</para>
        ///     <para>CASE: length &lt; 0 , RESULT: String is split from right to left.</para>
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>String array that has been split into substrings of equal length.</returns>
        /// <example>
        ///     <code>
        ///         string s = "1234567890";
        ///         string[] a = s.Split(4); // a == { "1234", "5678", "90" }
        ///     </code>
        /// </example>
        public static string[] Split(this string s, int length)
        {
            System.Globalization.StringInfo str = new System.Globalization.StringInfo(s);

            int lengthAbs = Math.Abs(length);

            if (str == null || str.LengthInTextElements == 0 || lengthAbs == 0 || str.LengthInTextElements <= lengthAbs)
                return new string[] { str.ToString() };

            string[] array = new string[(str.LengthInTextElements % lengthAbs == 0 ? str.LengthInTextElements / lengthAbs: (str.LengthInTextElements / lengthAbs) + 1)];

            if (length > 0)
                for (int iStr = 0, iArray = 0; iStr < str.LengthInTextElements && iArray < array.Length; iStr += lengthAbs, iArray++)
                    array[iArray] = str.SubstringByTextElements(iStr, (str.LengthInTextElements - iStr < lengthAbs ? str.LengthInTextElements - iStr : lengthAbs));
            else // if (length < 0)
                for (int iStr = str.LengthInTextElements - 1, iArray = array.Length - 1; iStr >= 0 && iArray >= 0; iStr -= lengthAbs, iArray--)
                    array[iArray] = str.SubstringByTextElements((iStr - lengthAbs < 0 ? 0 : iStr - lengthAbs + 1), (iStr - lengthAbs < 0 ? iStr + 1 : lengthAbs));

            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is an image link to the results of running this code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh3Ym.png

Comment: I noticed a problem with this code. You have `{str.ToString()}` at the end of your first IF statement. Are you sure you didn't mean `str.String`? I had a problem with the code above, made that change, and everything worked.

Comment: @gunr2171 It seems that if str == null, that line will also give a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Re *"by Marvin Pinto"*: Do you mean *"[by Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/8719393#8719393)"*?

Answer (score 6):

Personally I prefer my solution :-)

It handles:

- String lengths that are a multiple of the chunk size.
- String lengths that are *not* a multiple of the chunk size.
- String lengths that are smaller than the chunk size.
- NULL and empty strings (throws an exception).
- Chunk sizes smaller than 1 (throws an exception).

It is implemented as a extension method, and it calculates the number of chunks is going to generate beforehand. It checks the last chunk because in case the text length is not a multiple it needs to be shorter. Clean, short, easy to understand... and works!

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, int chunkSize)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("The string cannot be null.");
    if (chunkSize < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("The chunk size should be equal or greater than one.");

    int remainder;
    int divResult = Math.DivRem(value.Length, chunkSize, out remainder);

    int numberOfChunks = remainder > 0 ? divResult + 1 : divResult;
    var result = new string[numberOfChunks];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < numberOfChunks - 1)
    {
        result[i] = value.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize);
        i++;
    }

    int lastChunkSize = remainder > 0 ? remainder : chunkSize;
    result[i] = value.Substring(i * chunkSize, lastChunkSize);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be much faster and more efficient than using LINQ or other approaches used here.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Splice(this string s, int spliceLength)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if (spliceLength < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("spliceLength");

    if (s.Length == 0)
        yield break;
    var start = 0;
    for (var end = spliceLength; end < s.Length; end += spliceLength)
    {
        yield return s.Substring(start, spliceLength);
        start = end;
    }
    yield return s.Substring(start);
}
```

Comment: This *looks* like it does early checking, but it doesn't. You don't get an error until you begin enumerating the enumerable. You need to break up your function into two parts, where the first part does the argument checking, and then returns the results of the second, **private** part that does the enumeration.

Answer (score 5):

Simple and short:

```
// This means match a space or not a space
// (anything) up to 4 characters
var lines =
    Regex.Matches(
        str, 
        @"[\s\S]{0,4}").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Why not use `.`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an Rx implementation. It handles the `length % chunkSize != 0` problem out of the box:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Chunkify(this string input, int size)
{
    if(size < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("size must be greater than 0");

    return input.ToCharArray()
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(size)
        .Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()))
        .ToEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: What is "Rx"? Do you mean [ReactiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_extensions)? Or [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)? Or something else?

Comment: (Similar: [RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rx-java/info) and [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS))

Answer (score 4):

You can use [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) by Jon Skeet. Use [Batch](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) like:

```
string str = "1111222233334444";
int chunkSize = 4;
var chunks = str.Batch(chunkSize).Select(r => new String(r.ToArray()));
```

This will return 4 chunks for the string `"1111222233334444"`. If the string length is less than or equal to the chunk size `Batch` will return the string as the only element of `IEnumerable<string>`

For output:

```
foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(chunk);
}
```

and it will give:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

Comment: Among the authors of MoreLINQ I see _Jonathan Skeet_, but no _Jon Skeet_. So did you mean _the_ Jon Skeet, or what? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The best, easiest and generic answer :).

```
string originalString = "1111222233334444";
List<string> test = new List<string>();
int chunkSize = 4; // Change 4 with the size of strings you want.
for (int i = 0; i < originalString.Length; i = i + chunkSize)
{
    if (originalString.Length - i >= chunkSize)
        test.Add(originalString.Substring(i, chunkSize));
    else
        test.Add(originalString.Substring(i,((originalString.Length - i))));
}
```

Comment: Calculating the length in the last line is redundant, simply use the `Substring` overload that doesn't require the length parameter `originalString.Substring(i)`. Also you can use `>` instead of `>=` in your check.

Comment: @RacilHilan I will test the code changes with your suggestion and update the answer. I am glad somebody with such good reputation got time to review my code. :) Thanks, Sandeep

Comment: Straight forward answer. Simple and easy to understand.

Comment: In what way is it the best, easiest and generic answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31071837/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
   IEnumerable<string> retVal = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize))

   if (str.Length % chunkSize > 0)
        retVal = retVal.Append(str.Substring(str.Length / chunkSize * chunkSize, str.Length % chunkSize));

   return retVal;
}
```

It correctly handles input string length not divisible by chunkSize.

Please note that additional code might be required to gracefully handle edge cases (null or empty input string, chunkSize == 0).

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitEvery<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, int n)
{
    var ls = values.Take(n);
    var rs = values.Skip(n);
    return ls.Any() ?
        Cons(ls, SplitEvery(rs, n)) : 
        Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Cons<T>(T x, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    yield return x;
    foreach (var xi in xs)
        yield return xi;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 13 years ago"*

Answer (score 3):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, double chunkSize)
{
    // use integer division to determine how many chunks
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (int) Math.Ceiling(str.Length/chunkSize))
       // use the index of the item (thus 'i' param) to:
       .Select(i => new string(str
           // a: skip iterated chunks given
           .Skip(i * (int)chunkSize)
           // b: take the current chunk
           .Take((int)chunkSize)
           // force execution of select
           .ToArray()));
}
```

and another approach:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var x = "Hello World";
        foreach(var i in x.ChunkString(2)) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public static class Ext{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ChunkString(this string val, int chunkSize){
        // iterate over every character in the string
        return val.Select((x,i) => new {Index = i, Value = x})
                  // group those characters by chunk size using
                  // integer division
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Index/chunkSize, x => x.Value)
                  // reassemble grouped chars into strings
                  .Select(x => string.Join("",x));
                  // after looking at this solution
                  // .Select(x => new string(x));
                  // may be more efficient than the .Join operation
                  // i have not tested this
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26920095/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

**Six years later o_O**

Just because

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize, bool remainingInFront)
    {
        var count = (int) Math.Ceiling(str.Length/(double) chunkSize);
        Func<int, int> start = index => remainingInFront ? str.Length - (count - index)*chunkSize : index*chunkSize;
        Func<int, int> end = index => Math.Min(str.Length - Math.Max(start(index), 0), Math.Min(start(index) + chunkSize - Math.Max(start(index), 0), chunkSize));
        return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => str.Substring(Math.Max(start(i), 0),end(i)));
    }
```

**or**

```
    private static Func<bool, int, int, int, int, int> start = (remainingInFront, length, count, index, size) =>
        remainingInFront ? length - (count - index) * size : index * size;

    private static Func<bool, int, int, int, int, int, int> end = (remainingInFront, length, count, index, size, start) =>
        Math.Min(length - Math.Max(start, 0), Math.Min(start + size - Math.Max(start, 0), size));

    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize, bool remainingInFront)
    {
        var count = (int)Math.Ceiling(str.Length / (double)chunkSize);
        return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => str.Substring(
            Math.Max(start(remainingInFront, str.Length, count, i, chunkSize), 0),
            end(remainingInFront, str.Length, count, i, chunkSize, start(remainingInFront, str.Length, count, i, chunkSize))
        ));
    }
```

AFAIK all edge cases are handled.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "abc".Split(2, false))); // ab c
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "abc".Split(2, true))); // a bc
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "a".Split(2, true))); // a
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "a".Split(2, false))); // a
```

Comment: What about the "input is an empty string" edge case? I'd expect that, just like with Split, to return an IEnumerable with a single empty-string containing entry.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
List<string> SplitString(int chunk, string input)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    int cycles = input.Length / chunk;

    if (input.Length % chunk != 0)
        cycles++;

    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            list.Add(input.Substring(i * chunk, chunk));
        }
        catch
        {
            list.Add(input.Substring(i * chunk));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but maybe you should use  if ((i+1) * chunk >= input.Length) instead of try/catch as exceptions are for exceptional cases.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42344295/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** ***  *** ***  *** ***  *** ***  *** ***  *** ***  *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

Changed slightly to return parts whose size  is not equal to chunkSize:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize)
{
    var splits = new List<string>();
    if (str.Length < chunkSize) 
    { 
        chunkSize = str.Length;
    }
    splits.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize).Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize)));
    splits.Add(str.Length % chunkSize > 0 ? str.Substring((str.Length / chunkSize) * chunkSize, str.Length - ((str.Length / chunkSize) * chunkSize)) : string.Empty);
    return (IEnumerable<string>)splits;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see the use of back-casting that `List` to `IEnumerable`; all that does is hiding List-specific functions you might want to use. There is no downside whatsoever to just returning the `List`.

Answer (score 2):

An important tip if the string that is being chunked needs to support all Unicode characters.

If the string is to support international characters like , then split up the string using the System.Globalization.StringInfo class. Using StringInfo, you can split up the string based on number of text elements.

```
string internationalString = '';
```

The above string has a Length of 2, because the `String.Length` property returns the number of Char objects in this instance, not the number of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an straightforward answer:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || chunkSize<1)
            throw new ArgumentException("String can not be null or empty and chunk size should be greater than zero.");
        var chunkCount = str.Length / chunkSize + (str.Length % chunkSize != 0 ? 1 : 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
        {
            var startIndex = i * chunkSize;
            if (startIndex + chunkSize >= str.Length)
                yield return str.Substring(startIndex);
            else
                yield return str.Substring(startIndex, chunkSize);
        }
    }
```

And it covers edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
static List<string> GetChunks(string value, int chunkLength)
{
    var res = new List<string>();
    int count = (value.Length / chunkLength) + (value.Length % chunkLength > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    Enumerable.Range(0, count).ToList().ForEach(f => res.Add(value.Skip(f * chunkLength).Take(chunkLength).Select(z => z.ToString()).Aggregate((a,b) => a+b)));
    return res;
}
```

[demo](https://rextester.com/YLUBE4623)

Comment: this one keeps the remainder of the string (post split) even it is shorter than "chunkLenght", thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's my 2 cents:

```
  IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
  {
     while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
     {
        var chunk = str.Take(chunkSize).ToArray();
        str = str.Substring(chunk.Length);
        yield return new string(chunk);

     }

  }//Split
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62585022/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I took this to another level.  Chunking is an easy one-liner, but in my case I needed whole words as well.

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string orgString, int chunkSize, bool wholeWords = true)
{
    if (wholeWords)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (orgString.Length > chunkSize)
        {
            string[] newSplit = orgString.Split(' ');
            foreach (string str in newSplit)
            {
                if (sb.Length != 0)
                    sb.Append(" ");

                if (sb.Length + str.Length > chunkSize)
                {
                    result.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }

                sb.Append(str);
            }

            result.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
            result.Add(orgString);

        return result;
    }
    else
        return new List<string>(Regex.Split(orgString, @"(?<=\G.{" + chunkSize + "})", RegexOptions.Singleline));
}
```

Results based on a comment below:

```
string msg = "336699AABBCCDDEEFF";
foreach (string newMsg in Split(msg, 2, false))
{
    Console.WriteLine($">>{newMsg}<<");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Results:

```
>>33<<
>>66<<
>>99<<
>>AA<<
>>BB<<
>>CC<<
>>DD<<
>>EE<<
>>FF<<
>><<
```

Another way to pull it:

```
List<string> splitData = (List<string>)Split(msg, 2, false);

for (int i = 0; i < splitData.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($">>{splitData[i]}<<");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

New Results:

```
>>33<<
>>66<<
>>99<<
>>AA<<
>>BB<<
>>CC<<
>>DD<<
>>EE<<
>>FF<<
```

Comment: One thing I noticed with your expression for the else-branch (not whole words) - when I use that expression with a chunk size of 2 for a string "336699AABBCCDDEEFF", the return is of size 10, where the last string (item 9) is null. That is, the return should be 9 strings of length 2, not 10 strings. What am I missing?

Comment: Thats  because of the new string added to the end of each line, (RegexOptions.Singleline).

Comment: Added demo code to show it's results above.

Comment: Re *"Chucking"*: Do you mean *"[Chunking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chunk#Verb)"*?

Comment: Fixed, thanks.  Sometimes my fingers just type what they want, without a care in the world what my brain is saying.   ha.

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly build up on [João's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450836#1450836).

What I've done differently is in my method you can actually specify whether you want to return the array with remaining characters or whether you want to truncate them if the end characters do not match your required chunk length. I think it's pretty flexible and the code is fairly straightforward:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SplitFunction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "hello, how are you doing today?";
            string[] chunks = SplitIntoChunks(text, 3,false);
            if (chunks != null)
            {
                chunks.ToList().ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string[] SplitIntoChunks(string text, int chunkSize, bool truncateRemaining)
        {
            string chunk = chunkSize.ToString();
            string pattern = truncateRemaining ? ".{" + chunk + "}" : ".{1," + chunk + "}";

            string[] chunks = null;
            if (chunkSize > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                chunks = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(text,pattern)select m.Value).ToArray();

            return chunks;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
public static List<string> SplitByMaxLength(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    List<string> splitString = new List<string>();

    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
    {
        splitString.Add(str.Substring(index, 
                                      Math.Min(maxLength, 
                                      str.Length - index)));
    }

    return splitString;
}
```

Comment: You, eh, forgot the MaxLength parameter.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10980739/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember who gave me this, but it works great.  I speed tested a number of ways to break Enumerable types into groups.  The usage would just be like this...

```
List<string> Divided = Source3.Chunk(24).Select(Piece => string.Concat<char>(Piece)).ToList();
```

The extension code would look like this...

```
#region Chunk Logic
private class ChunkedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    class ChildEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        ChunkedEnumerable<T> parent;
        int position;
        bool done = false;
        T current;


        public ChildEnumerator(ChunkedEnumerable<T> parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            position = -1;
            parent.wrapper.AddRef();
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (position == -1 || done)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                return current;

            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!done)
            {
                done = true;
                parent.wrapper.RemoveRef();
            }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;

            if (position + 1 > parent.chunkSize)
            {
                done = true;
            }

            if (!done)
            {
                done = !parent.wrapper.Get(position + parent.start, out current);
            }

            return !done;

        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            // Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    EnumeratorWrapper<T> wrapper;
    int chunkSize;
    int start;

    public ChunkedEnumerable(EnumeratorWrapper<T> wrapper, int chunkSize, int start)
    {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ChildEnumerator(this);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

}
private class EnumeratorWrapper<T>
{
    public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        SourceEumerable = source;
    }
    IEnumerable<T> SourceEumerable { get; set; }

    Enumeration currentEnumeration;

    class Enumeration
    {
        public IEnumerator<T> Source { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public bool AtEnd { get; set; }
    }

    public bool Get(int pos, out T item)
    {

        if (currentEnumeration != null && currentEnumeration.Position > pos)
        {
            currentEnumeration.Source.Dispose();
            currentEnumeration = null;
        }

        if (currentEnumeration == null)
        {
            currentEnumeration = new Enumeration { Position = -1, Source = SourceEumerable.GetEnumerator(), AtEnd = false };
        }

        item = default(T);
        if (currentEnumeration.AtEnd)
        {
            return false;
        }

        while (currentEnumeration.Position < pos)
        {
            currentEnumeration.AtEnd = !currentEnumeration.Source.MoveNext();
            currentEnumeration.Position++;

            if (currentEnumeration.AtEnd)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        item = currentEnumeration.Source.Current;

        return true;
    }

    int refs = 0;

    // Needed for dispose semantics
    public void AddRef()
    {
        refs++;
    }

    public void RemoveRef()
    {
        refs--;
        if (refs == 0 && currentEnumeration != null)
        {
            var copy = currentEnumeration;
            currentEnumeration = null;
            copy.Source.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>Speed Checked.  Works Great!</summary>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunksize)
{
    if (chunksize < 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var wrapper = new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(source);

    int currentPos = 0;
    T ignore;
    try
    {
        wrapper.AddRef();
        while (wrapper.Get(currentPos, out ignore))
        {
            yield return new ChunkedEnumerable<T>(wrapper, chunksize, currentPos);
            currentPos += chunksize;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        wrapper.RemoveRef();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified (now it accepts *any* nonnull `string` and *any* positive `chunkSize`) [*Konstantin Spirin*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450797#1450797):

```
public static IEnumerable<String> Split(String value, int chunkSize) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
  else if (chunkSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chunkSize", "Chunk size should be positive");

  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, value.Length / chunkSize + ((value.Length % chunkSize) == 0 ? 0 : 1))
    .Select(index => (index + 1) * chunkSize < value.Length
      ? value.Substring(index * chunkSize, chunkSize)
      : value.Substring(index * chunkSize));
}
```

Tests:

```
  String source = @"ABCDEF";

  // "ABCD,EF"
  String test1 = String.Join(",", Split(source, 4));
  // "AB,CD,EF"
  String test2 = String.Join(",", Split(source, 2));
  // "ABCDEF"
  String test3 = String.Join(",", Split(source, 123));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based around other posters answers, along with some samples of usage:

```
public static string FormatSortCode(string sortCode)
{
    return ChunkString(sortCode, 2, "-");
}

public static string FormatIBAN(string iban)
{
    return ChunkString(iban, 4, "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}

private static string ChunkString(string str, int chunkSize, string separator)
{
    var b = new StringBuilder();
    var stringLength = str.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
    {
        if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength - i;
        b.Append(str.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        if (i+chunkSize != stringLength)
            b.Append(separator);
    }
    return b.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Buffer extensions from the [IX library](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx.Single.cs#L201)

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return str.Buffer(chunkSize).Select(l => String.Concat(l));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringHelper
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Hi my name is vikas bansal and my email id is bansal.vks@gmail.com";
        int offSet = 10;

        List<string> chunks = chunkMyStr(str, offSet);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<string> chunkMyStr(string str, int offSet)
    {
        List<string> resultChunks = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += offSet)
        {
            string temp = str.Substring(i, (str.Length - i) > offSet ? offSet : (str.Length - i));
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
            resultChunks.Add(temp);
        }

        return resultChunks;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can slightly improve your code: shift the increment expression `i += offSet` into your `for` expression.

Comment: Yet another code dump. An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31233093/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in this way too

```
string actualString = "1111222233334444";
var listResult = new List<string>();
int groupingLength = actualString.Length % 4;
if (groupingLength > 0)
    listResult.Add(actualString.Substring(0, groupingLength));

for (int i = groupingLength; i < actualString.Length; i += 4)
{
    listResult.Add(actualString.Substring(i, 4));
}

foreach(var res in listResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

If necessary to split by a few different lengths:

For example, you have date and time in the specified format string`strangeStr = "07092016090532";` 07092016090532 (Date:07.09.2016 Time: 09:05:32)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int[] chunkLength)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new ArgumentException();
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < chunkLength.Length; j++)
    {
        if (chunkLength[j] < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (chunkLength[j] + i > str.Length)
        {
            chunkLength[j] = str.Length - i;
        }
        yield return str.Substring(i, chunkLength[j]);
        i += chunkLength[j];
    }
}
```

Using:

```
string[] dt = strangeStr.SplitBy(new int[] { 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2 }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
var longString = new string('s', 3000);
var chunkLength = 1273;
var ratio = (double)longString.Length / chunkLength;
var countOfChunks = Convert.ToByte(Math.Round(ratio, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity));

for (byte i = 0; i < countOfChunks; i++)
{
    var remainingLength = longString.Length - chunkLength * i;
    if (chunkLength > remainingLength)
        chunks.Add(longString.Substring(i * chunkLength, remainingLength));
    else
        chunks.Add(longString.Substring(i * chunkLength, chunkLength));
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63007205/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public static List<string> DevideByStringLength(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    double a = (double)text.Length / chunkSize;
    var numberOfChunks = Math.Ceiling(a);

    Console.WriteLine($"{text.Length} | {numberOfChunks}");

    List<string> chunkList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++)
    {
        string subString = string.Empty;
        if (i == (numberOfChunks - 1))
        {
            subString = text.Substring(chunkSize * i,
                                       text.Length - chunkSize * i);
            chunkList.Add(subString);
            continue;
        }
        subString = text.Substring(chunkSize * i, chunkSize);
        chunkList.Add(subString);
    }
    return chunkList;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63789827/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(_string.Length / _chunkSize))); i++)
{
    var _currentChunk = _string.Substring(i * _chunkSize, Math.Min(_chunkSize, _string.Length - i * _chunkSize));
    // Do something with the current chunk 
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements **all** other answers.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
    public static string[] Split(string str, int chunkSize)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
            .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize)).ToArray();
    }
```