# Split string in 512 char chunks

Tags: c#, string, split

Maybe a basic question but let us say I have a string that is 2000 characters long, I need to split this string into max 512 character chunks each.

Is there a nice way, like a loop or so for doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you need 512 **char** chunks? Because that is different from 512 **bytes** which is a more common constraint.

Comment: @Henk: On the other hand, splitting *text* into chunks based on *bytes* would be pretty odd - the results would depend on the encoding.

Comment: Jon, yes, a common problem when re-assembling the text again. But some I/O channels operate in 512 byte blocks.

Comment: @Jon and @Henk: the `string` in C# is defined to contain UTF-16 characters internally, encoding is not relevant in memory, once you write it to disk (or elsewhere), encoding becomes relevant and influences the stored byte size.

Comment: Abel, I know and so does Jon. I was asking meep to confirm at what level the condition applies. 512 is a much rounder number for bytes than for chars.

Comment: ah, sorry, of course (I reacted on "would depend on encoding", I see now what you meant).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private IList<string> SplitIntoChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < text.Length)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(chunkSize, text.Length - offset);
        chunks.Add(text.Substring(offset, size));
        offset += size;
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

Or just to iterate over:

```
private IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < text.Length)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(chunkSize, text.Length - offset);
        yield return text.Substring(offset, size);
        offset += size;
    }
}
```

Note that this splits into chunks of UTF-16 code units, which isn't quite the same as splitting into chunks of Unicode code points, which in turn may not be the same as splitting into chunks of glyphs.

Comment: This algorithm (and its _compatibility_ with Unicode) has been discussed also on Code Review: [Split a string into chunks of the same length](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111925/13424).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Thanks - I've added a small note on the answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

using Jon's implementation and the **yield** keyword.

```
IEnumerable<string> Chunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    for (int offset = 0; offset < text.Length; offset += chunkSize)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(chunkSize, text.Length - offset);
        yield return text.Substring(offset, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of for vs my while... I'm trying to decide which is easier to read. You don't need the yield break at the end, btw.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the redundant yield break as @Jon mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Though this question meanwhile has an accepted answer, here's a short version with the help of regular expressions. Purists may not like it (understandably) but when you need a quick solution and you are handy with regexes, this can be it. Performance is rather good, surprisingly:

```
string [] split = Regex.Split(yourString, @"(?<=\G.{512})");
```

What it does? Negative look-backward and remembering the last position with `\G`. It will also catch the last bit, even if it isn't dividable by 512.

Comment: Useful for inspecting long strings in Immediate Window.

Comment: Why not? It's short, fast enough and clear (if you know regexes, personally I had to read it and test it 3 times). Nice version!

Answer (score 1):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)    
{   
    int len = str.Length;
    return Enumerable.Range(0, len / chunkSize).Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));    
}
```

source: [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/c-split-a-string-into-equal-chunks-each-of-size-4)

Comment: Fails to provide the final chunk in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I will dare to provide a more LINQified version of Jon's solution, based on the fact that the `string` type implements `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
private IList<string> SplitIntoChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    var chunks = new List<string>();
    int offset = 0;
    while(offset < text.Length) {
        chunks.Add(new string(text.Skip(offset).Take(chunkSize).ToArray()));
        offset += chunkSize;
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

Comment: I did consider that - particularly as MoreLINQ provides a nice Partition method for this sort of thing. However, the efficiency of this would be absolutely horrible :(

Comment: btw String, does not have an extension method for "Skip" you would have to do ToCharArray first.

Comment: and I know it implements *IEnumerable<char>* which makes it that much more baffling...

Comment: @Stan: the C# VS team hard-coded the string dropdown helpers: it is an exceptional case where you do not see the Framework-provided extensions methods. They found that clearer. The VB team decided contrary: here you do see the `IEnumerable<char>` extension methods in the dropdown helper.

Comment: ahh guys that explains it, thanks...and i was baffled by this for a few minutes hahaa

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answer may have the same flaw.
Given an empty text they will yield nothing.
We (I) expect at least to get back that empty string (same behaviour as a split on a char not in the string, which will give back one item : that given string)

so we should loop at least once all times (based on Jon's code) :

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks (string text, int chunkSize)
{
    int offset = 0;
    do
    {
        int size = Math.Min (chunkSize, text.Length - offset);
        yield return text.Substring (offset, size);
        offset += size;
    } while (offset < text.Length);
}
```

or using a for (**Edited** : after toying a little more with this, I found a better way to handle the case *chunkSize greater than text*) :

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks (string text, int chunkSize)
{
    if (text.Length <= chunkSize)
        yield return text;
    else
    {
        var chunkCount = text.Length / chunkSize;
        var remainingSize = text.Length % chunkSize;

        for (var offset = 0; offset < chunkCount; ++offset)
            yield return text.Substring (offset * chunkSize, chunkSize);

        // yield remaining text if any
        if (remainingSize != 0)
            yield return text.Substring (chunkCount * chunkSize, remainingSize);
    }
}
```

That could also be used with the do/while loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generic extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitToChunks<T> (this IEnumerable<T> coll, int chunkSize)
  {
    int skipCount = 0;
    while (coll.Skip (skipCount).Take (chunkSize) is IEnumerable<T> part && part.Any ())
    {
      skipCount += chunkSize;
      yield return part;
    }
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main (string[] args)
  {
    var col = Enumerable.Range(1,1<<10);
    var chunks = col.SplitToChunks(8);

    foreach (var c in chunks.Take (200))
    {
      Console.WriteLine (string.Join (" ", c.Select (n => n.ToString ("X4"))));
    }

    Console.WriteLine ();
    Console.WriteLine ();

    "Split this text into parts that are fifteen characters in length, surrounding each part with single quotes and output each into the console on seperate lines."
      .SplitToChunks (15)
      .Select(p => $"'{string.Concat(p)}'")
      .ToList ()
      .ForEach (p => Console.WriteLine (p));

    Console.ReadLine ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like?

```
Calculate eachLength = StringLength / WantedCharLength
Then for (int i = 0; i < StringLength; i += eachLength)
SubString (i, eachLength);
```