# Maximum number of occurrences a character appears in an array of strings

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

In C#, given the array :

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] {
  "test#test",
  "##test",
  "######", // Winner (outputs 6)
};
```

How can I find the maximum number of occurrences that the character `#` appears in a single string ?

My current solution is :

```
int maxOccurrences = 0;
foreach (var myString in myStrings)
{
    var occurrences = myString.Count(x => x == '#');
    if (occurrences > maxOccurrences)
    {
        maxOccurrences = occurrences;
    }
}

return maxOccurrences;
```

Is their a simplier way using linq that can act directly on the `myStrings[]` array ?

And can this be made into an extension method that can work on any `IEnumerable<string>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all let's project your strings into a sequence with count of matches:

```
myStrings.Select(x => x.Count(x => x == '#')) // {1, 2, 6} in your example
```

Then pick maximum value:

```
int maximum = myStrings
    .Select(s => s.Count(x => x == '#'))
    .Max(); // 6 in your example
```

Let's make an extension method:

```
public static int CountMaximumOccurrencesOf(this IEnumerable<string> strings, char ch)
{
    return strings
        .Select(s => s.Count(c => c == ch))
        .Max();
}
```

However there is a big **HOWEVER**. What in C# you call `char` is not what you call character in your language. This has been widely discussed in other posts, for example: [Fastest way to split a huge text into smaller chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431128/1207195) and [How can I perform a Unicode aware character by character comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27229589/1207195) then I won't repeat everything here. To be "Unicode aware" you need to make your code more complicate (please note code is wrote here then it's untested):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateCharacters(string s)
{
    var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s.Normalize());
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return (string)enumerator.Value;
}
```

Then change our original code to:

```
public static int CountMaximumOccurrencesOf(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string character)
{
    return strings
        .Select(s => s.EnumerateCharacters().Count(c => String.Equals(c, character, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
        .Max();
}
```

Note that `Max()` alone requires collection to don't be empty (use `DefaultIfEmpty()` if collection may be empty and it's not an error). To do not arbitrary decide what to do in this situation (throw an exception if it should happen or just return 0) you can may make this method less specialized and leave this responsibility to caller:

```
public static int CountOccurrencesOf(this IEnumerable<string> strings,
    string character,
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
{
    Debug.Assert(character.EnumerateCharacters().Count() == 1);

    return strings
        .Select(s => s.EnumerateCharacters().Count(c => String.Equals(c, character, comparison ));
}
```

Used like this:

```
var maximum = myStrings.CountOccurrencesOf("#").Max();
```

If you need it case-insensitive:

```
var maximum = myStrings.CountOccurrencesOf("à", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Max();
```

As you can now imagine this comparison isn't limited to some *esoteric* languages but it also applies to invariant culture (en-US) then for strings that must always be compared with invariant culture you should specify `StringComparison.InvariantCulture`. Don't forget that you may need to call `String.Normalize()` also for input character.

Comment: Bah, just beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this. Note the usage of `DefaultIfEmpty`, to not throw an exception if `myStrings` is empty, but revert to `0`.

```
var maximum = myStrings.Select(e => e.Count(ee => ee == '#')).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `Linq` combined to `Regex`:

```
myStrings.Select(x => Regex.Matches(x, "#").Count).max();
```