# How to add <br> in string after counting particular characters

Tags: asp.net

I want to display description of product in gridview, but i want to display only 15 characters on one line, I want to break it after 15 characters, I have written countchar function as follows:

```
public int CountChars(string value)
{

    bool lastWasSpace = false;

    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        result++;
        lastWasSpace = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and called function as:

```
string description="sdfsdfsd sdfsdf sdfsdf asdfsa dfsda safsaf sdfdf sdfs sdfsdf sdff sdf ";

CountChars(description);
```

And i want to check:

```
if(result>15)
{
 after every 15 characters i want to break the line. 
}
```

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I think your "CountChars" is wrong, lastWasSpace is always false and never read. result is not declared.

Comment: Do you want to add the <br> in the middle of a word?

Comment: I think if I understand correctly that the CountChars method can be resumed to `value.Trim().Length`

Answer (score 0):

```
public string AddSpaces(string value) {
    int result = 0;
    string new_value = "";
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        result++;
        new_value += c.ToString();
        if ( result == 15 ) { 
            new_value += "<br />"; 
            result = 0; 
        }
    }
    return new_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.Length > 15)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (i = 0; i < value.Length; i+=15)
        sb.Append(value, i, Math.Min(value.Length - i, 15)).Append("<br/>");
    value = sb.ToString();
}
```

Not tested

Comment: why is it giving error to "Maths.Min" in asp.net c#,is it necessary to import any namespace

Comment: I removed the s, obviously it's Math and not Maths.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/c-split-a-string-into-equal-chunks-each-of-size-4/1450808#1450808) (to split the string)

```
string str = "111122223333444455";
int chunkSize = 4;
string tmp = String.Join("<br />", str.ToCharArray().Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i }).GroupBy(o => o.Index / 4).Select(g => new String(g.Select(o => o.Char).ToArray())).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(tmp);
```

It produces the following result :

```
1111<br />2222<br />3333<br />4444<br />55
```