# How to split a string into a fixed length string array?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split, .net-1.1

I have a long string like this

```
dim LongString as String = "123abc456def789ghi"
```

And I want to split it into a string array. Each element of the array should be in 3 characters length

For example,

```
Dim LongArray(5) As String
LongArray(0)  = "123"
LongArray(1)  = "abc"
LongArray(2)  = "456"
LongArray(3)  = "def"
LongArray(4)  = "789"
LongArray(5)  = "ghi"
```

How do I split it using VB.net code?

Comment: What should happen if the string length is not a multiple of 3?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It is always of multiple of 3

Comment: @BlackJack: I have tried it. But what is the `delimiter` value for my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/c-split-a-string-into-equal-chunks-each-of-size-4

Comment: @Yoga Fire: So the method can throw an exception if it's not?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The string length will be checked before the split operation, so no need for exception

Comment: @Yoga Fire: I would personally prefer to check the arguments within the method, but there we go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work.

```
 Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim LongString As String = "123abc456def789ghi"
        Dim longlist As New List(Of String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(LongString.Length / 3) - 1
            longlist.Add(LongString.Substring(i * 3, 3))
        Next
        For Each s As String In longlist
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And this should work in .Net 1.1

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim LongString As String = "123abc456def789ghi"
        Dim longlist(Convert.ToInt32(LongString.Length / 3) - 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(LongString.Length / 3) - 1
            longlist(i) = (LongString.Substring(i * 3, 3))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(LongString.Length / 3) - 1
            Console.WriteLine(longlist(i))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use LINQ like so:

```
' VB.NET
Dim str = "123abc456def789ghij"
Dim len = 3
Dim arr = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / len).Select (Function(x) str.Substring(x * len, len)).ToArray()
```

```
// C#
var str = "123abc456def789ghij";
var len = 3;
var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / len).Select (x => str.Substring(x * len, len)).ToArray();
```

Note this will only take *complete* occurrences of length (i.e. 3 sets in a string 10 characters long).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but LINQ is not supported for .Net v1.1

Comment: @Yoga Perhaps you should have written you were still using ancient instruments!

Comment: @xanatos in his defense it has a .net1.1 tag to the question.

Comment: @chrissie1: Only since xanatos added it.

Answer (score 2):

This C# code should work:

```
public static string[] SplitByLength(string text, int length)
{
    // According to your comments these checks aren't necessary, but
    // I think they're good practice...
    if (text == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    }
    if (length <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
    }
    if (text.Length % length != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException
            ("Text length is not a multiple of the split length");
    }
    string[] ret = new string[text.Length / length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = text.Substring(i * length, length);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Reflector converts that to VB as:

```
Public Shared Function SplitByLength(ByVal [text] As String, _
                                      ByVal length As Integer) As String()
    ' Argument validation elided
    Dim strArray As String() = New String(([text].Length \ length)  - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ret.Length - 1
        strArray(i) = [text].Substring((i * length), length)
    Next i
    Return strArray
End Function
```

It's possible that that isn't idiomatic VB, which is why I've included the C# as well.

Comment: @Jon Why is reflector convertin integer division to non-integer (VB.NET) divisions? Shouldn't it convert ``\`` to `/`? It doesn't know the prereq that the number are always divisible by 3.

Comment: @Jon Told by one of the four persons with the gold badge of VB.NET :-) It was more a question of "is this a bug of the reflector or what"

Answer (score 1):

I'm splitting the string by 35.

```
var tempstore ="12345678901234567890123456789012345";

for (int k = 0; k < tempstore.Length; k += 35) {
    PMSIMTRequest.Append(tempstore.Substring(k,
      tempstore.Length - k > 35 ? 35 : tempstore.Length - k));
    PMSIMTRequest.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
}

messagebox.Show(PMSIMTRequest.tostring());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LongString As String = "1234567"

Dim LongArray((LongString.Length + 2) \ 3 - 1) As String

For i As Integer = 0 To LongString.Length - 1 Step 3
    LongArray(i \ 3) = IF (i + 3 < LongString.Length, LongString.Substring(i, 3), LongString.Substring(i, LongString.Length - i))           
Next

For Each s As String In LongArray
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

There are some interesting parts, the use of the `\` integer division (that is always rounded down), the fact that in VB.NET you have to tell to DIM the maximum element of the array (so the length of the array is +1) (this is funny only for C# programmers) (and it's solved by the -1 in the dim), the "+ 2" addition (I need to round UP the division by 3, so I simply add 2 to the dividend, I could have used a ternary operator and the modulus, and in the first test I did it), and the use of the ternary operator IF() in getting the substring.

Answer (score 0):

Last array is missing:

```
Public Function SplitByLength(ByVal text As String, _
                                  ByVal length As Integer) As String()

  ' Argument validation elided
  Dim strArray As String() = New String((text.Length \ length)  - 1) {}
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To text.Length - 1
      strArray(i) = text.Substring((i * length), length)
  Next i

  ' Get last array:
  ReDim Preserve strArray(i)
  strArray(i) = text.Substring(i * length)
  Return strArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some more logic to @jon code. This will work perfectly for the string which has length less than length passed.

```
 Public Shared Function SplitByLength(ByVal [text] As String, ByVal length As Integer) As String()

    Dim stringLength = text.Length
    Dim arrLength As Integer = ([text].Length \ length) - 1 + IIf(([text].Length 
                                             Mod length) > 0, 1, 0)
    Dim strArray As String() = New String(arrLength) {}

    Dim returnString As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim remLength As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To strArray.Length - 1
      remLength = stringLength - i * length
      If remLength < length Then
        strArray(i) = [text].Substring((i * length), remLength)
      Else
        strArray(i) = [text].Substring((i * length), length)
      End If
    Next i

       Return  strArray
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
Function splitN(str As String, n As Integer) As String()
  For i = 0 To Len(str) Step n + 1
    Try
      str = str.Insert(i + n, "|")
    Catch
    End Try
  Next
  Return str.Split("|")
End Function
```

You can call it like: `splitN("abc123def456frg987ef", 3)`