# How does this code about arrays work?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split

The code bellow splits a string into strings of seven characters each into an array. Can someone please explain how it works in detail?

```
Dim orig = "12344321678900987"
Dim res = Enumerable.Range(0,orig.Length\8).[Select](Function(i) orig.Substring(i*8,8))
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]  SO is not a tutorial service.  Expend some effort doing research on MSDN.

Comment: [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) reveals the inner workings of the .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim orig = "12344321678900987"
Dim res = Enumerable.Range(0,orig.Length\8).[Select](Function(i) orig.Substring(i*8,8))
```

This code uses a few neat language tricks to reduce the amount of code required for digesting the string into smaller segments. Starting from inside out, first there is a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
Function(i) orig.Substring(i * 8, 8)
```

This is a fancy way of creating Subs or Functions 'inline.' It essentially equates to:

```
Function subStr(ByVal i As Integer) As String
    Return orig.Substring(i * 8, 8)
End Function
```

The next part uses the [Enumerable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx), and its [Range method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) to generate a series of numbers to feed into the lambda.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, orig.Length \ 8)
```

This is a fancier way of writing:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To (orig.Length \ 8)
    'Do something with i
End For
```

`.[Select]` is a little bit of magic that takes the current `i` in the loop (or range), and allows working with it. In this example it's:

```
subStr(i)
```

So this neat, one-line job can also be written as:

```
Dim orig As String = "12344321678900987"
Dim res as String()
For i As Integer = 0 To (orig.Length \ 8)
    Array.Resize(res, res.Length + 1)
    res(res.Length - 1) = subStr(i)
End For

Function subStr(ByVal i As Integer) As String
    Return orig.Substring(i * 8, 8)
End Function
```

Comment: For other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376987/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-fixed-length-string-array?rq=1