# How do I split a string every 7th charecter in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am having difficulties trying to figure out the syntax. I have a line of binary in a variable and i want to know how to to split that string every 7th character so i can put it in an ascii table to find its equivalent.

Comment: [First result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774392/how-to-split-a-string-by-x-amount-of-characters) googling "vb.net split string every x characters"

Comment: This question has been asked and resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376987/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-fixed-length-string-array

Comment: i have tried those in my code and none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario, you can also do a substring to satisfy your requirement.

```
Dim theString As String = "w3rs0fd90as90f9sda0faf"

Dim FirstSevenCharacters as String= theString.Substring(0, 7)

Dim CharactersAfterTheFirstSeven as String= theString.Substring(7, theString.Length - 7)
```