# Split String for debug.writeline?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

Is there anyway to split a string for the every 714 character? this is due to the debug.writeline limitation in c#

Comment: Yes there is - [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: and there is no limitation if you are doing .WriteLine() to a log file perhaps you may what to consider that as well.. but would need to see what code you have thus far..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I'd use `Substring`:

```
string myString = "Some very long string you need to output.";

for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i += 714) {
    Debug.WriteLine(myString.Substring(i, Math.Min(714, myString.Length - i)));
}
```

Or, for a fancy one-liner:

```
foreach(var s in Regex.Matches(myString, ".{,714}")) Debug.WriteLine(s.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}
```

From [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

And make your own writeline method

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using this

```
        int chunkSize = 700;
           int stringLength = str.Length;
           for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
           {
               if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength - i;
               Debug.WriteLine(str.Substring(i, chunkSize));

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that should do the trick (sans LINQ just to keep things clear):

```
public static string[] SplitLength(this string val, int length)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < val.Length; i += length)
    {
        parts.Add(val.Substring(i * length, length));
    }

    return parts.ToArray();
}
```