# Place every n-th character in string at n-7 position

Tags: c#, string

I have string with 0's and 1's. It looks like this:

```
1110011011010000...
```

With spaces for better visualisation (original string from my program doesn't contain spaces)

```
11100110 11010000 ...
```

Every eight elements must be a letter of Unicode in binary.

What i need to do, is put every last 0 or 1 of each letter (every 8th element in full string) to the first place for this letter, so this string would be like this:

```
0111001101101000...
```

With spaces for better visualisation (original string from my program doesn't contain spaces)

```
01110011 01101000 ...
```

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at [C# string members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You might want to just use hex values, use the >> or << operators to role the bits left or right and convert back into binary string representation for your output, if that's how you need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings are immutable so i would use StringBuilder to move characters

```
    var s =  "1110011011010000";
    var window = 8; // the tail of string which is shoreter than 8 symbols (if any) will be ignored
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s);
    for(int i = 0; i <= s.Length-window; i=i+window)
    {
        char c = sb[i+window-1];
        sb.Remove(i+window-1,1);
        sb.Insert(i,c);         
    }
    string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting your string into chunks of size eight ([here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450774/335858)).

This gives you an `IEnumerable<string>`. Take each string of length 8, and recombine its characters like this:

```
string orig = "11100110";
string res = orig.Substring(1)+orig[0];
```

Finally, merge back the parts processed in the above way to get your final string ([here is how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. The method `ShiftChunkChars` takes a string and integer which depicts the amount of characters in each "chunk". Beware that this method does not work if the input string's length is not divisible by `chunkSize`.

```cs
string ShiftChunkChars(string original, int chunkSize)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[chunkSize];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i += chunkSize)
    {
        char[] chars = original.Substring(i, chunkSize).ToCharArray();
        Array.Copy(chars, 0, buffer, 1, chunkSize - 1);
        buffer[0] = chars[chunkSize - 1];
        sb.Append(buffer);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Examples:

**1.**

```cs
void Main()
{
    int chunkSize = 8;
    string s = "11100110110100000111001101101000";
    ShiftChunkChars(s, chunkSize);
}
```

Output:

```cs
01110011011010001011100100110100
// Original with spaces: 11100110 11010000 01110011 01101000
// Result with spaces:   01110011 01101000 10111001 00110100
```

**2.**

```cs
void Main()
{
    int chunkSize = 4;
    string s = "11100110110100000111001101101000";
    ShiftChunkChars(s, chunkSize);
}
```

Output:

```cs
01110011111000001011100100110100
// Original with spaces: 1110 0110 1101 0000 0111 0011 0110 1000
// Result with spaces:   0111 0011 1110 0000 1011 1001 0011 0100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this very simple with Regex:

```
string formattedBinary = Regex.Replace("0111001101101000", ".{8}", "$0 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Not sure if I have undestood the question. In this case I looped twice because I had 16 chars.

```
string s = "1110011011010000";
char[] nc = s.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    char tmp = nc[i * 8 + 7];
    for (int j = 6; j > 0; j--)
    {
        nc[i * 8 + j + 1] = nc[i * 8 + j];
    }
    nc[i * 8] = tmp;
}
s = new string(nc);
```