# C# IEnumerable<string> and string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, ienumerable

i searched for a method to split strings and i found one.
Now my problem is that i can´t use the method like it is described.

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944374/4313408)

It is going to tell that i

> cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'.

The provided method is:

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int chunkLength)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new ArgumentException();
        if (chunkLength < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkLength)
        {
            if (chunkLength + i > str.Length)
                chunkLength = str.Length - i;

            yield return str.Substring(i, chunkLength);
        }
    }
}
```

How he said it is used:

```
string[] result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy(3); // [bob, joe, cat]
```

Comment: arrays do not implement IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh You can assign a `string[]` to an `IEnumerable<string>` The problem is the opposite: you cannot assign an `IEnumerable<string>` to a `string[]`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, [Arrays do implement IEnumerable<T>](https://ideone.com/d8rBt6),  since .NET Framework 2.0, but only at [run-time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx#remarksToggle). However, as mentioned by Dennis_E, this is not the root of the problem.

Comment: @soon: it's also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx): _"Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time..."_

Comment: Sure, and my comment has the same link under `run-time` words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `ToArray()` method:

```
string[] result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy(3).ToArray(); // [bob, joe, cat]
```

You can implicitly convert `Array` to `IEnumerable` but cannot do it vice versa.

Comment: I tried now for over 2 Hours and never thought that its so Simple.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you could even modify directly the method to return a `string[]`:

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static string[] SplitByToArray(this string str, int chunkLength)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new ArgumentException();
        if (chunkLength < 1) throw new ArgumentException();

        var arr = new string[(str.Length + chunkLength - 1) / chunkLength];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkLength, j++)
        {
            if (chunkLength + i > str.Length)
                chunkLength = str.Length - i;

            arr[j] = str.Substring(i, chunkLength);
        }

        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If somehow you end up with this:
`IEnumerable<string> things = new[] { "bob", "joe", "cat" };`
you can transform it into `string[]` like this:
`string[] myStringArray = things.Select(it => it).ToArray();`