# convert a hex string to corresponding emoji string

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a string with emoji `""` starting from this string `"D83DDC71"`. For doing that I'm trying to convert the string above in this string `"\uD83D\uDC71"`.

If i use this code it work (textbox shows  as expected):

```
textbox.Text += "\uD83D\uDC71";
```

but if i use this it doesn't work (textbox shows exact text  "\uD83D\uDC71" instead of single character):

```
textbox.Text += sender.Code.ToString("X").insert(4, @"\u").insert(0, @"\u");
```

What is the right way to convert hex representation of an emoji to a corresponding C# string (UTF-16)?

Comment: the problem is that if i put into this "\uD83D\uDC71" in to the textbox it work, but if i append \u to this string  "D83DDC71" i only get a string and not an emoji

Comment: the standard one of windowsphone

Comment: Are you trying to output "person with blond hair"  ?

Comment: You could split the string into 4 char chunks & the rejoin them with "\u" separator. See here to split into chnaks : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size & here for joining https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: emoji in general, but in this case yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string containing two shorts in hexadecimal form, so you need to parse them first. My example uses an [overload of `Convert.ToInt16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wxkt09k.aspx) which also accepts an integer specifying the base of the integers in the string which, in our case, is 16 (hexadecimal).

```
string ParseUnicodeHex(string hex)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i+=4)
    {
        string temp = hex.Substring(i, 4);
        char character = (char)Convert.ToInt16(temp, 16);
        sb.Append(character);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Please note that this method will fail if the string's length isn't divisible by 4.

The reason this works:

```
textbox.Text += "\uD83D\uDC71";
```

is because you've got a **string literal** containing [unicode character escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx). When you compile your program, the compiler replaces these escape sequences with the correct unicode bytes. This is why you cannot just add `\u` in front of the characters during execution to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Okay. It seems you have a string which gives the hexadecimal of each of the UTF-16 code units of the character U+1F471 ().

Since `char` represents a UTF-16 code unit, split the string into two 4-character chunks, parse that into an int as hexadecimal, cast each to `char` and then combine them into a string:

```
var personWithBlondHair = ""
  + (char)int.Parse("D83DDC71".Substring(0, 4), NumberStyles.HexNumber)
  + (char)int.Parse("D83DDC71".Substring(4, 4), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

As per https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTgXfG

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
        string str = "D83DDC71";
        string emoji = string.Join("", (from Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\S{4}")
            select (char) int.Parse(m.Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray());
```

This will Separate your string 4 by 4 into array of strings. then it will convert each of strings into char. Finally it will Join all the chars into one string as emoji. all in one line.

Comment: What `@"\u" + m.Value` supposed to do?

Comment: ex : `m.Value` will be `"D83D"`. then it will be `"\uD83D"` @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Have you seen the question? Which is basically "why `"\uD83D\uDC71"` produces emoji while `@"\u"+ "d83d" + @"\" + "DC71"` does not"... So not sure how your post answers it. Additionally `\d` not going to match letters, but that is less interesting.

Comment: No, it will be `@"\uD83D"` and you need `"\uD83D"`. But it won't even be that because you are passing `""` instead of `str` to the regular expression matching. Also the regular expression is looking for decimal digits, not hex digits.

Comment: @JonHanna that was typo. i try this. maybe i need to convert m.Value to unicode char. but i thought this may work

Comment: There are still no matches for `\d{4}` in `str`, and still no point adding `@"\u"` to things.

Comment: yes. it should be `\S`. i fixed it. however i used your algorithm to convert to char. @JonHanna

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov see the edit. how ever using regex was just an idea but the point was to convert unicode string into char.

Comment: Looks correct to me now. I'd personally not use regex for such thing as splitting string into fixed size chunks but that completely opinion based :).