# Error while executing Python3 x Selenium Webdriver script: RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 117 is too big

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I got an error while executing Python x Selenium Webdriver script in chromium. It seems like script did his job, but i don't like this messeges in console.
Does anybody know how to fix that?

> [10112:9544:0823/174401:ERROR:latency_info.cc(164)] RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 117 is too big.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211373/python-selenium-send-keys-giving-warning-about-size ?

Comment: @danielfranca Yeah, exactly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you are sending or fetching large amount of data in one go.  to avoid that in python you can divide it into small chunks. which will solve the problem.

you can use chunk generator or the library:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    # Yield successive n-sized chunks from l
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

**or**

```
from boltons import iterutils
somelong_str = ' your data '
iterutils.chunked(somelong_str, 128)
```

refer : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211373/python-selenium-send-keys-giving-warning-about-size)