# divide string into list

Tags: c#, string

I have address `String` like `"abc 201 lmn road pqr near xyz building state maharashtra navi mumbai, 4212001 .... "`

I want to split this string to List like

```
List<string> addrList = new List<string>();
addrList.add("abc 201 lmn road pqr near");
addrList.add("xyz building state maharashtra ");
addrList.add("navi mumbai, 4212001");
```

I tried the following function

```
private string[] splitToNChar(string inputString, int chunkSize)
    {

        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i += chunkSize)
        {
            myList.Add(inputString.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        }
        return myList.ToArray(); 
    }
```

but it has an **exception** when I pass chunk size as `40` characters like

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception eee : Index and length must refer to a location within the
>   string.

Comment: You have to make sure that index+length < string.Length.

Comment: what is that you're trying to achieve? split string based on space or after a specific number of characters?

Comment: For actual methods to accomplish the task as opposed to explaining why you got that error, there are several ideas at [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450774/1115360).

Comment: Obviously he is trying to split each number of character in this case every 40 character but the problem is after a while his string has <40 character so when application tries to substring(i,40) it gave error. As Andrew said there must be a check before substring

Answer (score 0):

If `inputString` is `"abc 201 lmn road pqr near xyz building state maharashtra navi mumbai, 4212001 .... "`

The result of your extended function is:

```
private string[] splitToNChar(string inputString, int chunkSize)
{
    if (chunkSize > inputString.Length)
        throw new Exception("input string (" + inputString.Length + ") is smaller than chunksize (" + chunkSize + ")");

    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i += chunkSize)
    {
        if (i + chunkSize < inputString.Length)
            myList.Add(inputString.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        else
            myList.Add(inputString.Substring(i)); //ADD REST OF STRING
    }
    return myList.ToArray();
}
```

Output:

```
[0]  abc 201 lmn road pqr near
[1]   xyz building state mahar
[2]  ashtra navi mumbai, 42120
[3]  01 ....
```

I hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: what to do if there is one word like in output 'maharashtra' it gets separated like 'mahar' & 'ashtra'. for such condition there should not be splitting it shoud include whole word there.

Comment: You could split after a defined amount of words. It's depends on your data model, maybe you can share it, and I will take a look.