# How can I divide string into 3 parts?

Tags: c#, split

I want ask something about split string. Example:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
```

I want to divide str into 3 parts so parts look like:

```
string str1 = "1,2,3";
string str2 = "4,5,6";
string str3 = "7,8,9,10";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: seems it is x y problem what actually want to achieve.

Comment: What is criteria behind division of string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

Comment: As suggested by @HamzaHaider  you can check it will help you more

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
public static string SplitString(string data,int size)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % size == 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            sb.Append(data[i]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            int size = 3;
            string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
            string[] splitArray = str.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();
            string[] results = splitArray.Select((x,i) => new { index = i, number = x})
                .GroupBy(x =>  (x.index  < size * (splitArray.Length/size)) ? (x.index / (splitArray.Length/size)) : (x.index / (splitArray.Length/size)) - 1)
                .Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.number)))
                .ToArray();
```