# Splitting a string into evenly-sized chunks

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have a challenge to solve which is slitting a string into evenly-sized chunks.

Examples
Given the `string s = "abcdefg"` and `chunks = 3`, return `["abc", "de", "fg"]`. Note that the remainder of 1 was distributed to the first element in the list.

Given the `string s = "abcdefgh"` and `chunks = 3`, return `["abc", "def", "gh"]`. Again, note that the remainder of 2 was distributed to the first element in the list followed by the second element in the list.

So, I have this solution from an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size/1450796) but the "evenly" isn't consider

```
        public static IEnumerable<string> Iterator(string s, int chunks)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += s.Length - chunks)
            {
                if (i + chunks > s.Length) chunks = s.Length - i;
                yield return s.Substring(i, chunks);

            }

        }


        public static string[] Result(string s, int chunks)
        {
            if (chunks <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            return Iterator(s, chunks).ToArray();
        }
```

Second example would pass with this but the first doesn't, how do I adjust this to pass both test?

Comment: Try debugging (can even be done with pen and paper). How would you do it as human?

Comment: Try `/` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the number of chunks with the chunk size.

You must calculate the chunk size with:

```
int chunkSize = s.Length / chunks;
```

If the length of the string is not divisible by `chunks`, this will truncate the result because integer arithmetic is performed here. E.g., if the string size is 7 and `chunks = 3`, then this will yield `2`.
And you have a remainder of `1`. If the string size was `8`, the chunk size would still be `2`, but the remainder would be `2`. Now, you must distribute this remainder among the chunks.

You can get the remainder with the modulo operator `%`:

```
int remainder = s.Length % chunks;
```

Since you want the first chunks to be bigger, we now attribute this remainder to the first chunks:

```
int start = 0;
while (start < s.Length)
{
    int thisChunkSize = chunkSize;
    if (remainder > 0)
    {
        thisChunkSize++;
        remainder--;
    }
    yield return s.Substring(start, thisChunkSize);
    start += thisChunkSize;
}
```

---

If you need an even better distribution, you can use floating point arithmetic and round. The `MidpointRounding` tells what happens when rounding a value with a `.5` fraction.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EvenIterator(string s, int chunks)
{
    int start = 0;
    var rounding = new[] { MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity, 
                           MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity };
    int r = 0;
    while (start < s.Length) {
        int chunkSize = (int)Math.Round((double)(s.Length - start) / chunks, rounding[r]);
        r = 1 - r; // Swap the rounding
        yield return s.Substring(start, chunkSize);
        start += chunkSize;
        chunks--;
    }
}
```

A test with `"abcdefghijklmno"` and chunk size `6` gives:

```
[ "abc", "de", "fgh", "ij", "klm", "no" ]
```

Comment: Very true, I see my mistake now. Thank you