# Split a string by a number for get multiple string values

Tags: c#

Hi want to get a string cutted by a number like **"abcdefgh"** (split by **4**) string[] = "ab, cd, ef, gh".

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, i don't found something do what i want. It's everytime split by character like "\" or something with delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate: [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}
```

This answer was my favorite.

Comment: How do i import it in a string[]? Sorry im new to c#

Comment: string[] array = Split("abcdefgh",4).ToArray();

or do you mean "abcdefgh" has to be a string array?