# specified splitting of string

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do the following:

```
string str = "[A]     [C]     [E] [F]";
```

and then splitting the string down to a collection looking like:

```
List<string> myList = {"[A]", "   ", "[C]", "   ", "[E]", "[F]"}
```

In text: Is there a way to split the string by taking 3, then skipping 1. There is no ending space. Otherwise the following had worked fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450797/14375615

I can't just add 1 to length, that just caused an error because the last item wasn't 4 chars long

Comment: _"splitting the string"_ - ironically there is a member called `string.Split`

Comment: In your expected output there is no space between [E] and [F], where did it go? Typo or is there another rule to apply here?

Comment: Going by that, the spaces in `str` are 5, but in `myList`, they are 3 each.

Comment: You guys didn't read the question thoroughly. Quote "split the string by taking 3, then skipping 1" answers both the comments.

Comment: @Maku It dawned on me the second I read your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try different approach than method indicated in the other question. It's more straight forwardly handling the last segment if its length is smaller than chunkSize:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize, int gapSize)
{
    var index = 0;
    
    while (index < str.Length - chunkSize - 1)
    {
        yield return str.Substring(index, chunkSize);
        index += chunkSize + gapSize;
    }
    
    if (str.Length - index > 0)
    {
        yield return str.Substring(index, str.Length - index);
    }
}
```

Then usage:

```
 Split(str, 3, 1)
```

will produce desired result.

Comment: Thanks very much.I'd never come to this conclusion myself! But this block really makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a viable solution if you don't mind using Lists:

```
string str = "[A]     [C]     [E] [F]";
List<string> test = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
bool looping = true;

do
{
    test.Add(str.Substring(index, 3));

    str = str.Remove(0, 3);

    if (str.Count() > 0)
        str = str.Remove(0, 1);
    else if (str.Count() == 0)
        looping = false;
} while (looping);

foreach (var substr in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(substr);
}
```