# How can I split a string into chunks based on specific length?

Tags: c#, substring

I have the following string:

```
 string input = "A123   B12345 777"
```

The expected result as an array is as below,

```
    A123   B12345 777
```

But the actual result is

```
   A123   B12345
```

In the below code, the substring is not getting the last value. The size of the last value is just three characters.

```
SplitString(input, 7)

private  IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string str, int size)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / size)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * size, size));
}
```

Comment: I think you need to format your 'expected result' a bit more clearly. To me, that looks exactly the same as the input string and I would guess the function doesn't need to exist! Use `[`, `,` and `]` to show where you expect the split values to start and end. Also show us what number you are passing for the `size` parameter

Comment: I want to split the string in a specific length (7), and also want yo include the last section if the size is less than 7 chars

Comment: Evaluate `str.Length / size` in your debugger.

Comment: And find out what happens if your specified length is more than is available from that start position

Comment: "Needs more focus", on the other hand, is perfectly clear. Analysis is required in order to focus the question on the thing that is actually being wondered about.

Answer (score 2):

You got your code from [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450797), which only works if the input string is an exact multiple in size of `size`.

Integer division rounds down, so you need to ceil it. Then you possibly try to take substring longer than the remainder of the string. So:

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string str, int size) => 
    Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(str.Length / (float)size))
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * size, Math.Min(str.Length - (i * size), size)));
```

Since .NET 6 you can also [use `.Chunk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459077/266143):

> ```
> var result = str
>    .Chunk(size)
>    .Select(x => new string(x));
> ```

Comment: I found another way to do this using the for loop and and also adding Ceiling to match the size

Comment: if str.length is a multiple of the size this answer will throw an error. For example 14 / 7 is 2 but the +1 will result in trying to pull 3 chunks. You need to use Math.Ceiling(str.length / size) or Math.Floor((str.lenght / size) + 0.5)

Comment: @R.Laney no, it won't throw, but you're right, it'll return an empty string for the last part in that case. Edit: fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ has a handy Chunk method for grouping things like this.

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string str, int size)
{
    return str.Chunk(size).Select(c => new string(c));
}
```

```
string input = "A123   B12345 777";
var result = SplitString(input, 7);
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
// Result: ["A123   ","B12345 ","777"]
```